# Dynamic legend labels for ggsurvplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, survival-analysis, survminer

I have a general question related to dynamic labels and titles for ggsurvplot.
Is it possible to provide dynamic legend labels and legend title to the ggsurvplot function when using it in nested list using `map` from package purrr?

- The dataset I used is the NCCTG Lung Cancer Data `lung{survival}` and slightly adapted include ECOG scores below 3
- The code below dynamically creates survival plots for each of the prognostic factors (sex and ECOG score, defined in the varnames). However, I can't figure out how to add dynamic `title`,`legend.labs` and `legend.title` to the arguments within the `ggsurvplot` function as they need to be provided as a character vector that should change with each varname (sex and ph.ecog).

[image: plotspreview]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

HTJ

```
varnames <- c("sex", "ph.ecog")

lung <- lung %>% filter(ph.ecog<3)

res.tabs <- lung  %>%
  gather(key=VAR, value, varnames) %>%
  nest( data = -VAR) %>% mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ coxph(Surv(time, status) ~  value, data = .x)),
    survfit = map(data, ~ survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ value , data = .x, conf.type ="log")),
    plots = ggsurvplot(survfit, data, conf.int = TRUE, title = "???", legend.labs = "???", legend.title = "???"))
```

Comment: Did you pay any attention to the warning message? "Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
ℹ Use `all_of(varnames)` instead of `varnames` to silence this message."

Comment: There is currently no error message: I just don't know how to point `legend.title` or `legend.labs` to the correct elements in the object I'm creating (`res.tab`). I  figured I could recode the dataframe (using `recode` to convert 1 to "Male" and 2 to "Female") but actually I'm interested to know how the general principle works. 
in addition, thanks for the all_off tip